# Cypher: Match node on optional/nullable parameter

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a parameter "title" that may or may not be defined. If the parameter is defined I want to match nodes that has that parameter as a property.

```
MATCH (movie:Movie {title: {title}})
```

If the parameter is not defined, I don't want to match by that property and instead just return all movies. I.e. I want to filter the results by the parameter if it is present. Is this possible in one query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to conditionally match the title. Try this

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)
WHERE {title} IS NULL OR movie.title = {title}
```

Consider also leaving the conditional logic in the code and keeping your query clean:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)
WHERE movie.title =~ {isEmpty(title) ? '.*' : title}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: How would I use this in a `MERGE`-command with create and set branches? If a parameter is set it will be overwritten but if its not the old value should be used.

Comment: @EmilS. sounds like you're looking for a ternary (or conditional) expression in Neo4j. There isn't one. There ***is*** a way to do this, but I'd strongly suggest moving your conditional logic out of the query and into your code. If you'd really rather keep your conditional logic in the query (despite my suggestion), you can use the `CASE` keyword. I can better help you if you ask a new question and provide some details of what you're trying to do. (if you do create a new question, post the link here)

Comment: @EmilS. basically you would do `WITH CASE
  WHEN var IS NULL then matchedNode.var
  ELSE var
END AS newvar MERGE () ON MATCH SET matchedNode.var=newvar`

Comment: @EmilS. don't forget to upvote questions and answers that you find useful

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** this is possible, see the other answer.

I don't think this is possible. As soon as the query compiler finds a parameter, it will try to resolve it. If the parameter is not defined, the compiler will throw an Exception immediately - see the [`QueryState.getParam()`](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/61cf94c66e7a8c7053bb8cc8c336751a651c6307/community/cypher/cypher-compiler-3.1/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v3_1/pipes/QueryState.scala#L57) method. (If you are using Neo4j through a driver, this will result in another exception, e.g. with the Java driver, this will result in a [`ClientException`](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/1.0/org/neo4j/driver/v1/exceptions/ClientException.html).)